# Possbile to long press button and change its text in Android

Tags: android, button, long-press

I am able to long press a button and change its text using clipboard on 5.0 and above.
On long pressing cursor appears and clipboard can be opened.

Any solution other that disabling the button ? I have tried setting onLongClickListener as null.Here is my button :

```
<Button
            android:id="@+id/btn1"
            style="@style/ButtonRegular"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/md_8dp_margin"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:minWidth="@dimen/width_280dp"
            android:padding="12dp"
            android:text="abc"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />
```

In my app when you longpress clipboard can be opened to chnage button text

Comment: More detail about question?

Comment: I have a button in my app. It has some text inside it . I long press on button a cursor appears , i can click on cursor to show paste and clipboard options. Thorugh paste i can change the text on button

Comment: `button.setEnabled(false)`

Comment: i dont want to disable button

Comment: Please post the code

Comment: @AnuraagBaishya well its just a button nothing much

Comment: You can't put a cursor on a button. You could put an edittext behind the button and when  long clicking on the button you could make the button invisible and then focus the Edittext. After typing your text in the edittext in  onFocusChanged() of the edittext make the button reappear and then set the text from the edittext to the button

Comment: What I gather from your code is there nothing wrong with the button. Do you by any change have a text view or something behind the button? Or did you overlap a fragment and an activity and put elements at the same place?

Answer (score 1):

It was my mistake. I was adding below line in button style which caused issue

```
<item name="android:inputType">textCapWords</item>
```