# Long-press on Button to Change Text

Tags: android, button, keyboard

I have several buttons in my app which have single character numbers on them (such as '1','2', '3', ...).  As it is, when the user clicks a button the text on that button changes from a digit to a letter (such as 'A', 'B' or 'C'...) and will change back should the user click it again.  This all works well and good as the characters and digits are essentially hard programmed into the app however I am wanting to enable the user to enter 'custom' characters displayed on buttons through the use of a long-click.  For instance, instead of the first button only showing '1' or 'A' I would like for the user to be able to do a long press on the button and select say 'X' from the keyboard then have the button display this value.

I have done a lot of searching on how to do this but all the examples I come across all refer to reading input for an EditText rather than a Button (or TextView).  I have attempted to use an "InputMethodManager" as discussed in the [Developer Docs](https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/visibility.html) (as well as many other places) but I don't really understand how it should be used and simply copying the example code into my 'onLongClick(...)' method doesn't work, and probably isn't the right approach anyhow.

Probably the most promising lead I've been able to find is this one called [Possbile to long press button and change its text in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37206806/possbile-to-long-press-button-and-change-its-text-in-android), which contains the comment:

> You can't put a cursor on a button. You could put an edittext behind the button and when long clicking on the button you could make the button invisible and then focus the Edittext. After typing your text in the edittext in onFocusChanged() of the edittext make the button reappear and then set the text from the edittext to the button

Which sounds promising though the thread is a little short on details.

As it is I have extended the regular Button class to handle my requirements so I can add a dummy EditText to my 'CustomButton' if that will get me through.

If it's of any value here is my feeble attempt to capture keyboard input with a dummy EditText:

```
private class MyLongClickListener implements View.OnLongClickListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(final View view) {
        final CustomButton button = (CustomButton) view;

        EditText editText = button.getEditText();

        if (editText.requestFocus()) {
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)
                    getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.showSoftInput(view, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

But execution just blows right through the `showSoftInput` and exits the method without showing anything, and certainly doesn't give any opportunity to enter a character.

What would be the best way to implement this?

Comment: using onlongclicklistener

Comment: How do you get `EditText` from `CustomButton `?

Comment: I just have a simple 'getter' method at access it.  So the `CustomButton` class has a local EditText called `EditText mKeyboardReader;` and the `getEditText` simply returns this object: `public EditText getEditText() { return mKeyboardReader; }`

Comment: I could have of course just created a temporary one with `new EditText(...)` but in this instance I just had one contained within the object itself.  Probably not the best option but, you know, I was just trying things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it this way.

Create a custom view that contains a `Button` and an `EditText`.

```
public class MyView extends RelativeLayout {


public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    addViews();
}

public MyView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    addViews();
}

private void addViews() {
    View view = inflate(getContext(), R.layout.my_layout, null);
    addView(view);
}
}
```

my_layout.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:singleLine="true"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="Some Text"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="30sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and change onLongClickListener like this

```
 private class MyLongClickListener implements View.OnLongClickListener {
  EditText editText;
  TextView textView ;
 @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
            editText =(EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText);
            textView =(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            editText.bringToFront();
            textView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            editText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            if (editText.requestFocus()) {
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)
                        getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.showSoftInput(editText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);

            }
            textView.setText(editText.getText().toString());
            editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                    if(actionId== EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE){
                        editText.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        textView.bringToFront();
                        textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        textView.setText(editText.getText().toString());
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });

            return true;
        }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for that Adithya.  However, after spending almost the entire weekend on this I am still at a loss I'm afraid.  As it was I had a lot of trouble getting the OnLongClickListener to activate. In particular I found I had to set the "LongClickable" attribute on the RelativeLayout to "true" and set BOTH the "Clickable" and "LongClickable" attributes of the Button itself to "false" as well as set the "Visible" attribute on the EditText to either "INVISIBLE" or "GONE" (simply disabling the "clickable" properties of the EditText seems not to be sufficient to let the click "go through").

Comment: However, even though I was able to eventually get the event to fire on the RelativeLayout the InputMethodManager still seems to have no effect.  Setting the EditText to "VISIBLE" allows one to 'click' in the 'box' (which does indeed bring up the keyboard as one would expect) however the "requestFocus()" method does not do this automatically regardless of weather you leave the EditText visible at the end of the handler or not.  Is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: Also, the "bringToFront()" method doesn't really seem to do as I would expect. It seems to mess with my layout in ways I can't quite workout and overall doesn't seem to affect which elements are "clickable" (or even visible) as far as I can tell.

Comment: I've edited the code. Made some changes ,tested it and it works.

Comment: Hmm, it's almost working...  What is "Delete.this.getSystemService..."?  The compiler is unable to resolve the 'Delete' symbol.

Comment: Sorry. let me clean that up,its from my test activity. you can use `getApplicationContext()` instead.

Comment: No worries.  "getApplicationContext()" does the job.  This solution however is still taking two clicks.  One long press to make the EditText visible, then a second click in the 'box' to actually bring the keyboard up.  Is there a way to get it to do this 'second click' automatically?  Oh, and... The solution actually works better for me if I comment out the "bringToFront()" lines.

Comment: yeah use `editText` instead of `view` in `imm.showSoftInput(view, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);`
`